# Removing ASP.NET WebForms 'App_Themes' directory crashes the App Pool

Tags: asp.net, webforms, application-pool, app-themes

I recently began working on a large ASP.NET WebForms project.

The project was using the `App_Themes` directory with a lot of disorganized CSS and image resources.

I discovered that every CSS file in the theme's directory is loaded whether I want it or not, and they're all loaded in alphabetical order.

I obviously prefer to have more control and flexibility over my CSS and front-end resources, I moved them all to a separate directory then deleted the entire `App_Themes` folder.

This seemed like a simple matter of just moving resources, but after deploying to our production server the system soon became unstable and the App Pool was repeatedly crashing.

Restoring the `App_Themes` directory made the system stable again, but this makes no sense to me. The `App_Themes` folder, and any possible dependencies it may have, just seems like a strange black box that I cannot figure out and cannot seem to move away from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`App_Themes` is one of the "special directories" in ASP.Net. While it may not be required (you won't see them these days by default), they maybe referenced in configuration (`web.config`), any skinned controls, Pages, etc. - and perhaps that is why the app was being unstable after you removed the folder (broke all references to it).

Check for such references - you can (re)move css files from the themes defined so you can start with a blank slate if that is what you want. Unless you can find and remove all the references to theme usage in your app, avoid modifying the directory structure.

App_Themes can be powerful. You can easily change the look (aka "theme) your entire site simply with one change in web.config

```
<system.web>
    <!-- chage this value to "fall" in the Fall -->
    <pages theme="Summer" />
</system.web>
```

The "Summer" theme setting above maps to "Summer" subfolder in `App_Themes` containing the stylesheets/skins of the Summer theme. If you have "Fall" theme, then that maps to same named subfolder in `App_Themes`...

Ref: [ASP.Net Themes/Skins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcyt4fxb%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

hth

Comment: Thank you for your response. I realize the App_Themes directory is one of those "special directories", as you mentioned. Which is why I wasn't certain if there may be some black box dependencies that I'm unaware of.

I did remove the theme="XXXX" value from the web.config, but I suspect it didn't get properly pushed to our production environment due some imperfections in our deployment process. Now I'm almost certain this is the problem. I just wasn't sure if there may be any other references I need to check.